# Unhandled Exception when try to create MSIX installer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, windows, powershell, dart, msix

I was trying to create MSIX installer by following this instruction https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/windows/building

However, when I tried running  `dart run msix:create` I encountered this exception:

```
Building package executable... (12.7s)
Built msix:create.
running "flutter build windows"...     36.4s
building msix files...                 -Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified.

  Command: powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive "new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(\"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/msix-3.16.1/lib/assets\test_certificate.pfx\",
        \"1234\") | select -expandproperty Subject -First 1"
#0      _ProcessImpl._start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:401:33)
#1      Process.start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:38:20)
#2      _runNonInteractiveProcess (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:578:18)
#3      Process.run (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:49:12)
#4      SignTool._executePowershellCommand (package:msix/src/sign_tool.dart:84:21)
#5      SignTool._getCertificateSubjectByFile (package:msix/src/sign_tool.dart:139:53)
#6      SignTool.getCertificatePublisher (package:msix/src/sign_tool.dart:38:25)
#7      Msix._buildMsixFiles (package:msix/msix.dart:126:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      Msix._createMsix (package:msix/msix.dart:102:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      Msix.create (package:msix/msix.dart:59:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/msix-3.16.1/bin/create.dart:4:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried adding MSIX config and create a self-signed certificate, but the problem persists. Does anybody know what to do to fix this problem?